# Nexus S sensor events -- have any one got their hands on?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sdk-2.3, nexus-s

Has anyone tried testing SensorEvents on Nexus S with gingerbread 2.3
What all SensorEvents does it support ?
Specifically I am looking for these :

Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY

Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION

and

Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE

Can someone provide output of these events ? Does it support all of them ?
This question is related to my old post for separating gravity from accelerometer readings found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377288/how-to-remove-gravity-factor-from-accelerometer-readings-in-android-3-axis-accele).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the latest SDK downloaded a couple days ago (Android 2.3 API level 9) I see all the types you list. On a Nexus S a sensor listener for TYPE_GYROSCOPE and SENSOR_DELAY_UI generates a sensor changed event about every 10 msec:

> e SensorEvent  (id=830009808440)
>       accuracy    0
>       sensor  Sensor  (id=830009014296)
>           mHandle 5
>           mLegacyType 0
>           mMaxRange   34.906586
>           mMinDelay   1200
>           mName   "K3G Gyroscope sensor" (id=830009014352)
>           mPower  6.1 
>           mResolution 0.0012217305
>           mType   4
>           mVendor "STMicroelectronics" (id=830009014448)
>           mVersion    1
>       timestamp   99044897424000
>       values   (id=830009808472)
>           [0] 0.02687807
>           [1] -0.009773844
>           [2] -0.0012217305

For TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR I get an event about every 60 msec:

> e SensorEvent  (id=830009257568)
>       accuracy    3
>       sensor  Sensor  (id=830009236640)
>           mHandle 1601335158
>           mLegacyType 0
>           mMaxRange   1.0 
>           mMinDelay   20000
>           mName   "Rotation Vector Sensor" (id=830009236696)
>           mPower  7.03
>           mResolution 5.9604645E-8
>           mType   11
>           mVendor "Google Inc." (id=830009236792) 
>           mVersion    1
>       timestamp   99327490002000
>       values   (id=830009257600)
>           [0] 0.47573996
>           [1] -0.0030247832
>           [2] -0.004710396

For TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION events also come in around every 60 msec:

> e SensorEvent  (id=830009389592)
>       accuracy    3
>       sensor  Sensor  (id=830009013408)
>           mHandle 1600940398
>           mLegacyType 0
>           mMaxRange   19.6133 
>           mMinDelay   20000
>           mName   "Linear Acceleration Sensor" (id=830009013464)
>           mPower  0.23
>           mResolution 0.009576807 
>           mType   10
>           mVendor "Google Inc." (id=830009013568) 
>           mVersion    1
>       timestamp   99619963498000
>       values   (id=830009389624)
>           [0] -0.07089697 
>           [1] 0.041391253 
>           [2] -0.06359482

For TYPE_GRAVITY events come in around every 60 msec:

> e SensorEvent  (id=830009037864)
>       accuracy    3
>       sensor  Sensor  (id=830009017880)
>           mHandle 1600615030
>           mLegacyType 0
>           mMaxRange   19.6133 
>           mMinDelay   20000
>           mName   "Gravity Sensor" (id=830009017936)
>           mPower  0.23
>           mResolution 0.009576807 
>           mType   9
>           mVendor "Google Inc." (id=830009018016) 
>           mVersion    1
>       timestamp   99772462046000
>       values   (id=830009037896)
>           [0] 0.030116666 
>           [1] 0.65991235
>           [2] 9.721399